# FreeBSD testing rtld

Tags: freebsd

For some reasons I'm trying to modify and test my own version of rtld (ld-elf.so.1). After every change I did to this linker I need to reboot system, bring it up from CD/DVD, install my version in /libexec/ and reboot system again. Sometimes it even doesn't run user space because of segmentation fault. I'm wasting a lot of time in such a procedure.

I'd like to ask how can I launch this linker from command line without reinstalling my rtld in /libexec and rebooting the system. Is it possible to run rtld similarly to Linux /lib/ld-linux.so.2?

I tried to run ld-elf.so.1 but every time I get segmentation fault. Probably I missed some parameters in rtld command line. Any suggestions how to run rtld from command line?

Maybe I could change the default interpreter for my executables?

Edit: As a filesystem for my rootfs I use UFS.

Comment: You should put in your question whether you have root on ZFS, and why you aren't using a jail.

Comment: Cant' you run a (minimal) system in a virtual machine, so you can fool around at will with it's setup?

Comment: @vonbrand I'm already running system in virtual machine, but it also needs AFAIK reboots, doesn't it? Temporarily I'm changing interpreter for my executable. Seems it works for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run rtld similarly to Linux `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`?

Yes, running just `/libexec/ld-elf.so.1 /path/to/your_binary` works fine on FreeBSD, just like it does on Linux.

> Maybe I could change the default interpreter for my executables?

Yes, you could do that when compiling binaries, via `cc -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/path/to/your_interpreter`. The `-Wl,..` is the way gcc/clang passes arguments directly to linker, you may have a look at the `ld(1)` manpage for an explanation of its `--dynamic-linker` and other flags.

> I tried to run `ld-elf.so.1` but every time I get segmentation fault.

The dynamic linker / interpreter should be compiled as position independent (`-pie`) and cannot itself depend on shared objects, or use another interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

> For my rootfs I use UFS.

That's a shame, because the ZFS answer is quite simple.  Perhaps you'll see it as a reason to switch.

As long as the static parts of the operating system are all on one dataset, you create a ZFS *clone* of the dataset, mount it in some subdirectory, modify the loader (or whatever you want to modify) there, and then create a jail with that subdirectory as its root.  This provides a copy-on-write copy of your operating system but with the modified loader, *in situ* as it would be if installed as the main loader (which *it is* as far as the jail is concerned).

(TrueOS showed the way with this, having a big dataset for the root and `/usr` and effectively prune points for separate datasets at the likes of `/var/*`, `/tmp`, and `/usr/{obj,src,ports,jails,home}`.)

What this approach does away with is the lengthy process outlined in the `jail` manual page, and chapter 14 of the *FreeBSD Handbook*, for setting up the jail directory tree, involving building an entire copy of the operating system inside the jail's root directory.  A ZFS clone is a quick copy-on-write, taking the real root dataset as its origin.